# Is there any way to invoke .net (version 4) dll in NSIS

Tags: dll, clr, nsis

I have a dll which is build using .net 4. I have tried using CLR plugin and system call in both am getting status as error but not exactly sure what is the reason. Sample snippet of CLR I have pasted down (In the below code snippet am getting an error as "I method not found in M dll", its actually considering only first letter)

Function Test

CLR::Call /NOUNLOAD 'Myexample_Logic.dll' 'MynameSpace.classname' 'Instance' 0

pop $0

MessageBox MB_OK $0

CLR::Destroy

FunctionEnd

Can someone help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No experience whatsoever with NSIS, but given from the error message (only first letter) you could attempt double quotes instead of single quotes? While NSIS seems to support all kinds of quotes, the [docs](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Call_.NET_DLL_methods_plug-in) of the plugin only mention double quotes. It also says you need .NET 2.0+ so that looks like .NET framework assemblies as such should be OK. Again, no experience here. YMMV.

Comment: @Christian.K Thanks for the reply. I have checked with double quotes as well nothing worked.